# In which episode did Naruto turn into Eight-Tails Chakra Mode while fighting Pain?

Tags: naruto

There's an episode in *Naruto* showing Naruto use the Eight-Tails Chakra Mode while he's fighting with Pain.

I have looked on Google and nothing came up. The only thing was that when he met Killer B.

Which episode is this?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "The only thing was that when he met Killer B."?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ep. 166 or around that in *Shippuden*.

It started in 166 and the fight started in 167 with Pain vs 8-tails. To be more precise, the whole ep. 167 was of 8-tails.

Comment: Please be precise with your answer. Provide timestamps or references to support your answer.

Comment: But it started in 166 and the fight started in 167 with pain vs 8 tails. TO be more precise the whole ep 167 was of 8 tails

Answer (score 1):

It's in Episode 167, Season 4. 5:51 is when he turns into the 8 tails.